# symfony form repeated bits

Tags: forms, symfony, symfony-2.8

I've got a couple of entities that use traits to get the same properties and same behaviour without repeating code.

A good example for this is "startDate" and "endDate" for blogposts, articles, or whatever you want to give a start/endDate for displaying purposes. (please don't ask why you want to give a blogpost an endDate).

As you can imagine, the form elements get repeated as well.

What would be the best approach to prevent repeating of this bit of code in my FormType's?

I've considered listeners/subscribers, but it isn't depending on the actual data.

I could use a trait as well here, and call a method in the trait. This would work quite well, but might look a bit weird. Also, this does not use any of symfony's form features that might do just what I want.

Is there any Symfony Form feature I can use here?

Comment: yes, they are mandatory fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution would be using a trait.

```
trait YourRepetitiveFieldsTypeTrait
{
    public function buildFormYourRepetitiveFields(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        // add form fields as you would normally
    }
}
```

Then include this trait in each Type you need it. And call the method in `buildForm`:

```
$this->buildFormYourRepetitiveFields($builder, $options);
```

The reason for the different method name is to avoid clashes when importing it in your main class.